# How to paste source code from IDE to posts directly?

Tags: visual-editor, formatting

I have tried `preformatted` button, `Paste as text` button or `Text` tab element before pasting source code, WordPress always stripped indent tabs and broke code formatting.

For example, the source code:

```
final class HtmlAttr
{
  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @param  string  $filter  A filter hook to modify the attribute(s).
   */
  function __construct(array $attrs, $filter = '')
  {
    // Something...
  }

  /**
   * Render attribute(s)
   */
  function __toString()
  {
    // Something...
  }
}
```

will become:

```
final class HtmlAttr
{
 /**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param string $filter A filter hook to modify the attribute(s).
 */
 function __construct(array $attrs, $filter = '')
 {
 // Something...
 }

 /**
 * Render attribute(s)
 */
 function __toString()
 {
 // Something...
 }
}
```

I'm using Atom IDE and can't figure out the right way to paste source code from IDE into WordPress TinyMCE Editor directly. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you use `<pre></pre>` around the code?

Comment: @toscho You meant adding `<pre></pre>` manually. Isn't it's equal to `preformatted` button or I have missed something?

Comment: Well, yes, but that button is available in the _visual_ editor only – which is stripping tabs on paste.

Comment: If you will use the text mode of the editor, the plugin [AddQuicktag](https://wordpress.org/plugins/addquicktag/) enhance optional the editor buttons for mask code and add the pre-tags.

Comment: @toscho Thank you! That help me understand the problem. I though that WordPress should have a built-in way to handle source code automatically but look like we have to enter `pre` element each time.

Comment: @bueltge That plugin looks great but I just want to insert simple source code into my posts. Maybe I will try it in the future. Thank you anyway! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling about adding `pre` element manually, I decided to create a shortcut button on TinyMCE Editor:

This is button class and hooks in my parent theme:

```
/**
 * EmbedSourceCodeButton
 *
 * @see  https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons
 */
final class EmbedSourceCodeButton
{
  /**
   * Name
   */
  const NAME = 'embedSourceCodeButton';

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  function init()
  {
    if ('post' !== $GLOBALS['current_screen']->post_type) return;

    add_action('mce_buttons', [$this, 'addButton']);
    add_action('mce_external_plugins', [$this, 'addPlugin']);
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'localizeLabels'], 10, 0);
  }

  /**
   * Localize labels
   */
  function localizeLabels()
  {
    wp_localize_script('jquery-core', self::NAME, [
      'title'        => __('Embed Source Code', 'textdomain'),
      'listboxLabel' => __('Language', 'textdomain'),
      'textboxLabel' => __('Source code', 'textdomain')
    ]);
  }

  /**
   * Add this button to TinyMCE
   *
   * @see  https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php#L624
   *
   * @return  array  $buttons
   */
  function addButton(array $buttons)
  {
    array_push($buttons, self::NAME);

    return $buttons;
  }

  /**
   * Add this plugin
   *
   * @see  https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php#L392
   *
   * @return  array  $plugins
   */
  function addPlugin(array $plugins)
  {
    $x = SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';

    if ( !isset($plugins[self::NAME]) )
      $plugins[self::NAME] = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/button' . $x . '.js';

    return $plugins;
  }
}
add_action('load-post.php', [new EmbedSourceCodeButton, 'init']);
add_action('load-post-new.php', [new EmbedSourceCodeButton, 'init']);
```

And this is `button.js` which is inside `asset/js` folder of my theme:

```
(function() {
  tinymce.PluginManager.add('embedSourceCodeButton', function(editor, url) {
    editor.addButton('embedSourceCodeButton', {
      text: false,
      icon: 'wp_code',
      onclick: function() {
        editor.windowManager.open({
          title: embedSourceCodeButton.title,
          body: [
            { // Unnecessary yet but may be helpful in the future.
              name: 'language',
              type: 'listbox',
              label: embedSourceCodeButton.listboxLabel,
              values: [
                {
                  text: 'PHP',
                  value: 'php'
                },
                {
                  text: 'CSS',
                  value: 'css'
                },
                {
                  text: 'HTML',
                  value: 'html'
                },
                {
                  text: 'Javascript',
                  value: 'javascript'
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              name: 'code_block',
              type: 'textbox',
              multiline: true,
              label: embedSourceCodeButton.textboxLabel
            }
          ],
          onsubmit: function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            var entities = {
              '&': '&amp;',
              '<': '&lt;',
              ">": '&gt;',
              '"': '&quot;',
              "'": '&#39;',
              '/': '&#x2F;'
            };
            // Encode HTML special chars before inserting into editor.
            var codeBlock = e.data.code_block.replace(/&|<|>|"|'|\//gm, function(s) {
              return entities[s];
            });
            editor.insertContent('<pre data-lang="' + e.data.language + '"><code>' + codeBlock + '</code></pre>');
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

Hope it can help someone who is lazy as me too. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried another editor?

You could try CKEeditor, according to some it does not mess with the code indents.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/

Comment: Thank for your response but the plugin is too much for my problem.